Spark getItem shortcut
I am doing the following in spark sql:
spark.sql("""
            SELECT
            data.data.location.geometry.coordinates[0]
            FROM df""")

This works fine, however I do not want to use raw SQL, I use dataframe API like so:
df.select("data.data.location.geometry.coordinates[0]")

Unfortunately this does not work:
AnalysisException: [DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE] Cannot resolve "data.data.location.geometry.coordinates[0]" due to data type mismatch: Parameter 2 requires the "INTEGRAL" type, however "0" has the type "STRING".;
'Project [data#680.data.location.geometry.coordinates[0] AS 0#697]
+- Relation [data#680,id#681,idempotencykey#682,source#683,specversion#684,type#685] json

I know that I can use the F.col api and go with a getItem(0), but is there a built-in way to have the shortcut of getItem?
'.' is the shortcut of getField is there one for array slicing?
Thank you for your insight

TL;DR; use selectExpr()
df.selectExpr('data.data.location.geometry.coordinates[0]')

Looks like indexing inside an array using [] is considered an expression, where as data.data.location... is considered a column name.
DataFrame.select() takes column name as arguments, so doesn't understand [0], what you want is DataFrame.selectExpr().
>>>
>>> df =  spark.createDataFrame([({
...     "data": {
...         "location": {
...             "geometry": {
...                 "coordinates": [41.84201, -89.485937]
...             }
...         }
...     }
... },)]).withColumnRenamed('_1', 'data')
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{data -> {location -> {geometry -> {coordinates -> [41.84201, -89.485937]}}}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- data: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)

>>>


>>> df.select('data.data.location.geometry.coordinates').show(truncate=False)
+----------------------+
|coordinates           |
+----------------------+
|[41.84201, -89.485937]|
+----------------------+

>>> df.select('data.data.location.geometry.coordinates[1]').show()
+--------------+
|coordinates[1]|
+--------------+
|          null|
+--------------+
>>>

>>> df.selectExpr('data.data.location.geometry.coordinates[1]').show()
+----------------------------------------------+
|data[data][location][geometry][coordinates][1]|
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                    -89.485937|
+----------------------------------------------+

>>> df.selectExpr(
...          'data.data.location.geometry.coordinates[0] as coord_lat',
...          'data.data.location.geometry.coordinates[1] as coord_long'
... ).show()
+---------+----------+
|coord_lat|coord_long|
+---------+----------+
| 41.84201|-89.485937|
+---------+----------+

>>>


That's perfect, easy and elegant. Thanks

this should do the trick:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(
    F.col("data.data.location.geometry.coordinates").getItem(0).alias("coord")
)


Try this:
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object

df.select(
    get_json_object("data", "$.data.location.geometry.coordinates[0]").alias("coordinates")
).show()

